# Probability of first basket made

Tags: probability

> Derp has to keep shooting free throws until he makes a basket.  Suppose Derp's chance of making a basket is only $8\%$ and that individual shots constitute independent events.  Let $X$ be the number of shots Derp takes, including the successful one at the end of the sequence.
>   (a)  What is the expected value of $X$?
>   (b)  What is the probability that Ted will make his 4th shot?
>   (c)  What is the probability that Ted won't have to take more than 4 shots?

Since this is a geometric distribution, for part a, I did 
$$E(X)=\frac{1-.08}{.08}=11.5$$

For part b, I did $P(X=4)=.08(1-.08)^4$

For part c, I did $P(X<4)=P(X=3)+P(X=2)+P(x=1)$.

Am I on the right track here? Mostly, I'm wondering if I'm correctly accounting for the "Let $X$ be the number of shots Derp takes, including the successful one at the end of the sequence". Should I round the $E(X)$ to $12$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are letting $X$ be the number of shots until the first successful one, which includes the successful. This is fine.

a) No. That formula is for a geometric random variable over $\{0,1,2,\dotsc\}$. The possible values for this geometric random variable is the set $\{1,2,3,\dotsc\}$. You might have been given a formula, or you can check the usual way $\sum xP(X=x)$ or using the tail sum formula, and find that it is $\frac{1}{p} = \frac{1}{.08} = 12.5$

b) It's only asking about the fourth shot. Since each shot is independent and has the same probability, then the answer is $8\%$. The question does not say that the fourth shot is the first successful one.

c) "Won't take more than 4" **includes** 4. So it should be
$$P(X\leq 4) = P(X = 1)+\dotsb+P(X = 4)$$
For one example, let's consider $P(X = 4)$. This means the fourth is successful, but the first three are not. By independence, we have $(1-.08)^3\cdot(.08) =0.06229504$

Comment: Wow I had no idea I was so wrong about everything ;_; Thanks!

Comment: No, I wouldn't say "so wrong about everything". Your ideas were in the right area, which is much better than some people. Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) and good luck!

Comment: on b): isn't the probability for the question $0.92^3$ since that is the chance that he misses all 3 before? or did i not understand the question?

Comment: @saturatedexpo As it is stated in OP, we are simply asked about trial number four. In other words, consider trial number four. What is the chance that it is successful? It is $8\%$ since we are told that any particular shot has an $8\%$ of being successful. Also, even if we wanted to find the chance that the fourth was the first success, you forgot to include the fourth shot being successful. You solution only says that the first three were successful. So, it really should be $(1-.08)^3\cdot (.08)$, if that was the question. This is the same as the example I gave in c).

Comment: @Max mmh, i meant i read "makes his 4th shot" as "Derp has missed the first 3 and throws a 4th time, hitting or not". If it was meant otherwise the question would be "hits on his 4th throw" or not?

Comment: @saturatedexpo I understand, and I am also inclined to believe that what you have stated is what the author *meant* (first successful shot was fourth one), but as it stands, it reads as "makes fourth shot, regardless of other shots". At that point, I believe it is a matter of language and not math.

Comment: @DERPYPENGUIN Please be aware of the recent conversation.

Comment: @Max ah ok, i'm not native, but i can understand that making can mean successing. I just didn't read it the first time that way hehe.

Comment: @saturatedexpo No problem, I understand. I completely agree. I also felt like that was what the author **meant**, but I feel like that is **not** what the problem actually says. Two ways to say what you and I thought would be "What is the probability that the first basket was on the fourth shot?", or simply "What is the probability that $X$ is equal to 4?". Good luck!

Comment: @Max actually the question b) and c) are completly strange, as now instead of Derp, Ted is the individual we have to say something about. But ok, probably bad copypasting.

Comment: @saturatedexpo I didn't notice! Haha.